# How to get an input value from template (datetimepicker input) and use it into the views.py in a function view

Tags: python, django

Hello guys I am startin with Django and I have a question about filter data.

I want to export data from a model using import_export module with a button in the template ( no form in the template is in the listview template) :

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'cmp:export' %}" role="button">Exportar Proveedores</a>`
```

datepicker input:

```
<div class="input-group date" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" id="{{fecha_exportacion}}" name="fecha_exportar" 
            class="form-control datetimepicker-input datepicker" data- 
            target="#datetimepicker"/>
<div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data- 
                                toggle="datetimepicker">
     <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
     </div>
</div>
```

urls.py:

```
path('proveedor_export',export,name='export')
```

views.py

```
def export(request):
    **date = request.GET.get('fecha_exportar')**
    user_selected_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y %m, %d')
    proveedor_resource = ProveedorResource()
    queryset = Proveedor.objects.filter(fc=user_selected_date)
    dataset = proveedor_resource.export(queryset)
    response = HttpResponse(dataset.csv, content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; 
                                     filename="proveedores.csv"'
    return response
```

But I do not know how retrieve the datepicker input value and pass it to the views for the variable date.

I tried with  request.GET.get('fecha_exportar') but the result is None.

Comment: An important Thing that I forgot: I want to export data with the selected date input where fc= created_date ...  Proveedor.objects.filter(fc=user_selected_date). I want to get the input value from html code to views.py